# Referencing the Objective-C selector of a method

Tags: swift, swift2

As of Swift 2.2, the following code gives the warning:

> No method declared with Objective-C selector'sync'

```
if let tabBarController = segue.destinationViewController as? TabBarController {
  tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = 
    UIBarButtonItem(title: "Upload", 
                    style: .Plain, 
                    target: tabBarController, 
                    action: "sync")
```

What should I replace `action: "sync"`it with to get rid of the warning?

I've tried:

```
Selector("sync") // The Xcode provided fix which yields the same warning
#selector(tabBarController.sync()) // Error: Argument of '#selector' does not refer to initializer or method 
Selector(tabBarController.sync()) // No error/warning but doesn't fire sync function
```

Comment: `#selector(TabBarController.sync)`

Comment: @AaronBrager Thanks it worked. So it must to be the class name? It seems `#selector(self.sync)` works where `target: self`

Comment: @doovers Yes, you specify the method signature (the "action") to be performed on a specific instance (the "target")

Comment: @AaronBrager Cool that makes sense now thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For solving of your issue at first read new [documentation](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0022-objc-selectors.md) about Selectors in Swift2.2.

Example:
Use `#selector(CLASS.sync)` instead of `Selector("sync")`. Where CLASS it is actual class that contains this method.

And this was done due to this reason:

> The use of string literals for selector names is extremely
>   error-prone: there is no checking that the string is even a
>   well-formed selector, much less that it refers to any known method, or
>   a method of the intended class. Moreover, with the effort to perform
>   automatic renaming of Objective-C APIs, the link between Swift name
>   and Objective-C selector is non-obvious. By providing explicit "create
>   a selector" syntax based on the Swift name of a method, we eliminate
>   the need for developers to reason about the actual Objective-C
>   selectors being used.

Comment: What if the method "sync" is private? The warning/error doesn't go away then. Any solution for that?

Comment: @PanxShaz you cannot call private method via selector because we are missing all point of the private function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misplaced the action function "sync". Keep it in your TabBarController because you have used TabBarController's instance as target. Code like below will work:

```
tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Upload", style: .Plain, target: tabBarController, action: "sync:")
```

keep below function in TabBarController:

```
func sync(sender: AnyObject){
    //your code here
}
```

Hope it solves your issue. :)